# SequelizeJS How to use 1 model and create multiple tables?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Was hoping to get some help with this since I've tried everything and the docs are basically completely useless when trying to figure out what to do here.

Essentially, I have a model called `Address`, which contains all the fields you'd expect.

This auto creates a table called Addresses and by itself works fine. However, I also want to make an "Address_History" table that uses the same model.

Basically, I want this so that in my route if a user enters a new address, it stores the old address in the history table and then puts the new one inside the addresses table.
I can do the actual code for this, but I just can't get this damn association to work in a way like I said above in regards to having 2 separate tables using the same model.

I've tried everything including the `as` keyword and all that seems to do is add an extra column, not a table.

Basically I want something like this (But working);

```
  User.hasOne(Address, {
    as: 'Address',
  });
  Address.belongsTo(User, {
    as: 'Address',
  });

User.hasMany(Address, {
  as: 'addressHistory',
});
Address.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'addressHistory',
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am in a similar situation... Any one could get a good answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `as` option in `hasMany()` function does not create a new table in your DB. To create a new table, you need to call `init()` or `define()`, which are static functions. However, you can keep your codes pretty much DRY by modularizing the ctor and options. For example,

```js
const AddressCommonCtor = { 
  // your common column fields here
};
const AddressCommonOptions = {
  // options here

  // Make sure `modelName` field is not included here
  // because you want to create two different tables with different names in your DB  
};

class Address extends Model {};
class AddressHistory extends Model {};

Address.init(AddressCommonCtor, AddressCommonOptions);
AddressHistory.init(AddressCommonCtor, AddressCommonOptions);
```

Then you can associate Address and AddressHistory with User like this:

```
User.hasOne(Address, {
    as: 'address',
  });
User.hasMany(AddressHistory, {
  as: 'addressHistory',
});
```